# Small Proof $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)\leq \lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Can I get a quick check to see if I have done this correctly.

[Limit proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m0zjv.jpg)

Assume By contradiction that $L_1>L_2$. Let $\epsilon = \frac{L_1-L_2}{2}$ then,

$\forall$ $\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $\delta_1>0$ such that if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta_1$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$

$\forall$ $\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $\delta_2>0$ such that if $0<|x-x_0|<\delta_2$ then $|g(x)-L|<\epsilon$

Therefore we get that,

$L_1-\frac{L_1-L_2}{2}<f(x)<L_1+\frac{L_1-L_2}{2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{L_1-L_2}{2}<f(x)<\frac{3L_1-L_2}{2}$

$L_2-\frac{L_1-L_2}{2}<g(x)<L_2\frac{L_1-L_2}{2}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{-L_1-3L_2}{2}<g(x)<\frac{L_1-L_2}{2}$

which means that $g(x)<\frac{L_1-L_2}{2}<f(x)$ then $g(x)<f(x)$ which is a contradiction.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you copy text to here directly to improve accessibility?

Comment: You should put the assumption $f(x)\le g(x)$ somewhere in the statement of the question.

Comment: I did I forgot to include that when I wrote it up in here thanks.

Comment: Probably $L$ is $L_1$ and $L_2$ and further, you assume something about $x$, such as $|x-x_0|<\min (\delta_1,\delta_2)$ or so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mention that the “wrong” inequality would hold for at least one $x$: just choose $x$ with $0<|x-x_0|<\min(\delta_1,\delta_2)$.

You can also do it without contradiction.

> Suppose $f$ and $g$ are defined over $D=(x_0-k,x_0)\cup(x_0,x_0+k)$ (for some $k>0$) and that, for $x\in D$, $f(x)\le g(x)$.
>
> Suppose also that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L_1$ and $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=L_2$ are finite. Then $L_1\le L_2$.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. There exists $\delta>0$ (and $\delta<k$) such that, for $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$,
$$
L_1-\varepsilon<f(x)<L_1+\varepsilon,
\qquad
L_2-\varepsilon<g(x)<L_2+\varepsilon,
$$
For such an $x$, we have
$$
L_1-\varepsilon<f(x)\le g(x)<L_2+\varepsilon
$$
which implies
$$
L_1-L_2<2\varepsilon
$$
Since $\varepsilon$ is arbitrary, we deduce $L_1-L_2\le 0$.